# where to use "be"

Tags: passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, conjugations

Can you please tell me which one is correct?

> I need a list in which all the variations **are** shown.
>
> I need a list in which all the variations **be** shown.

I sometimes see that "be" is used to have a passive structure however I cannot understand when to use this form.

Comment: *It is important that all variations be shown on the list.* Are you thinking of this kind of form? We also use *be* in some future forms: *will be shown*. Or with some modals: *should be, might be*.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is not with passive vs. active, but singular vs. plural:

> All variations (=plural) **are** shown. but:
>   One variation (=singular) **is** shown.

You use "be" to form the passive infinitive form:

> **to show** (active) but:
>   **to be shown** (passive).

Or, as examples:

> I beg you **to show** me your work. but:
>   I asked for your work **to be shown**.

Comment: @S Oguz might also have noticed *be* in the subjunctive case, in both active and passive constructions. See, for example, [this](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html). (It has some good examples but gives only an incomplete or partially correct explanation of the use of the subjunctive.) Feel free to copy or adapt any of this into your answer if you want.

Comment: Note that the subjunctive is not a [case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_%28linguistics%29).

Comment: @JimReynolds this is absolutely what I was looking for. for example;  "We suggested that you be admitted to the organization." Can I say "We suggested that you are being admitted to the organization". ???

Comment: Ah, snailboat is right. The subjunctive is a mood, not a case. Well, it is possible to say "We suggested that you are being admitted to the organization." But the meaning changes to: *at one point in the past, we told someone that we believed you are being admitted.*